# With Traits, should I use a T prefix and if yes put it before or after any other prefix?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, traits, pharo

When creating Traits in Pharo+Squeak, is it proper to use a T prefix like TMyTrait and if yes, should the T go before any other prefix like TMPMyTrait (where "MP" is the other prefix), or after, like MPTMyTrait

Answer (score 3):

This is only a convention that help you understand what your are writing.
So yes add the T.
Always add the T at the beginning so you can immediately see that it's a Trait

Cheers